# CollapsingToolbarLayout not collapsing when scrolling with RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml

I am using a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` for a collapsing tool bar and it works for the most part. When you start scrolling on any part of the page besides the `RecyclerView` it will scroll fine and the toolbar will collapse like it should. However when you do start scrolling on the `RecyclerView` it doesn't collapse the tool bar and doesn't look the best.

I've tried a lot of different solutions I've found online and none have seemed to help. I'm using `appcompat-v7:23.2.1`. Here's what the layout file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/movie_detail_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/movie_detail_backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cd_backdrop"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/movie_detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Movie Content here -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_out_yet_layout"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    tools:background="@drawable/green_square">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_out_yet_image_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        tools:src="@drawable/ic_checkmark"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/movie_detail_out_yet_layout"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/movie_detail_out_yet_layout"
                    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_release_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    tools:text="March 21, 2016"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_mpaa_rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="PG-13"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/h_plot"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/movie_detail_plot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/h_ratings"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movie_detail_no_ratings_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/unknown"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/movie_detail_rating_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <!-- Critics Section -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_critics_rating_box"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        tools:background="@drawable/orange_square"
                        tools:text="6.7"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_critics_rating_tv"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/critics_rating"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Audience Section -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_audience_rating_box"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        tools:background="@drawable/orange_square"
                        tools:text="6.7"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/audience_rating"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/h_cast"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movie_detail_no_cast_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/unknown"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/movie_detail_cast_member_rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For the RecyclerView, I set it to have a LinearLayoutManager and to my custom adapter. Any help would be great, it's been a couple weeks and I still haven't been able to figure this out.

[image: Scroll issue]

Edit: It appears to only happen when scrolling up. If the tool bar is collapsed and I scroll down, it does expand like it should. However, as before, when scrolling up it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Having the same issue here. Any success?

Comment: @henriqueromao nope, still having it...

Comment: I have tried everything I found and nothing worked. Determining a flag on the RecyclerView and other things.. Still having the same problem. That frustrating...